# how to deal with "hwclock: ioctl(RTC_RD_TIME) to /dev/rtc to read the time failed: Invalid argument"

Tags: raspberry-pi3, ioctl, hwclock

I am trying to set the system time using real time clock interfaced with my raspberry pi.I am getting the above mentioned error

Comment: It's quite hard to address your question since you don't shed light on what you actually do prior getting such an error. But I presume the following link with a seemingly correct solution may come in handy: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=364303#p364303 . Does it fix the issue for you?

Comment: You are perfectly right. This page was the solution: sudo hwclock --systohc -D --noadjfile --utc